# Groovy/Java: Method injection in JDK class not being seen from Java

Tags: java, groovy, code-injection, mop

I'm trying to inject code into the JDK class, `Integer`. The injection works as long as I stay within Groovy, but does not if I try to use the injected code from a Java client.

Here's a demo of the problem.

The following Groovy code...

```
// File: g.groovy
class G {
    public static void init() {
        println 'Constructor injected';
        java.lang.Integer.metaClass.constructor = { i -> 
            println "My constructor called for Integer($i)"
            def constructor = Integer.class.getConstructor(int.class)
            constructor.newInstance(i)
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        G.init();
    }
}

println 'Before injection'
new Integer(1);

G.init()

new Integer(1);
```

... gives me the correct output:

```
$ groovy g.groovy
Before injection
Constructor injected
My constructor called for Integer(1)
$
```

Now, I delete everything from `g.groovy` EXCEPT for `class G`:

```
// File: g.groovy
class G {
    public static void init() {
        println 'Constructor injected';
        java.lang.Integer.metaClass.constructor = { i -> 
            println "My constructor called for Integer($i)"
            def constructor = Integer.class.getConstructor(int.class)
            constructor.newInstance(i)
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        G.init();
    }
}
```

Then, I compile `g.groovy`:

```
$ groovyc g.groovy
$ ls *.class
G.class  G$_init_closure1.class
$
```

Then, I try to make use of the injection from `U.java`:

```
// U.java
public class U {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Creating a new integer");
        new Integer(1);

        G.init();

        System.out.println("Creating a new integer");
        new Integer(1);
    }
}
```

And the result I get is this:

```
$ javac U.java
$ java -cp .:/path/to/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar U
Creating a new integer
Constructor injected
Creating a new integer
$
```

The injection clearly didn't work!

Answer (score 3):

Java has no concept of the metaClass so this will not work from the Java side as you've seen

Comment: Oh boy! I have a need to intercept and override some legacy Java app for which I don't have source code. I thought Groovy would somehow inject its MOP related stuff into the Java `.class` files and I'll be done! What do I do now??

Comment: @Harry have a look at aspectj. I'm not an expert but I'm pretty sure you can weave aspects into bytecode without access to the corresponding source.

Comment: I had known about aspectj but was/am trying to avoid using it because I've never used it ever, and so, it would be too difficult for me (relative to Groovy MOP) to understand and use it at such a short notice :-(

Comment: You could also try with AST, are not that difficult (it's AOP) I think, but can't help too much because I've just played with them a bit